# Fluctuating accuracy of Autoencoder

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I am working on an Autoencoder in keras with the following setting: 185-86-32-2-32-86-185. The problem is that its accuracy is fluctuating. Also, it is giving a new accuracy at every run.

If this is due to the random uniform kernel initialization, how can I save the output values of the initializes in order to use them later?

#### My code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy makes no sense for an autoencoder, because you're essentially doing regression (from X to X), you should use a different metric instead, like [MSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), [MAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_absolute_error), [RMSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-mean-square_deviation).